# How can I display short URLs without file extention?

Tags: url, friendly-url, truncate

I've looked around but wasn't able to find what I was looking for. I'm looking for a way to automatically create short URLs displayed in the browser, not using a URL shortener. Basically I would like to re-create something like this:

```
idzr.org/1ptb
```

I upload screenshots to my server with "GrabUp" on a regular basis but it creates rather long URLs for example:

```
/2523e3c90d60f08e952215424e7c5d99.png
```

It's a bit annoying having to shorten them each time.
I have seen this method a lot lately with pretty much any file including html files. If this has been discussed already I'm sorry I'm posting it again. I just seem to be stuck.
Thanks in advance for any help & advice!

Comment: What webserver are you using for starters?

Comment: Are you asking how do you create you own URL shortening site?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, what webserver do you use.

1. You write rule for rewrite
   -- htaccess for Apache or equivalent for IIS
2. You push content to user thru your code, because browser doesn't know what content get from web server
   -- use http header - MIME type

Comment: Why would you start the answer to a question with, "I don't know"?  If you don't know, **don't answer**!